# MySql, Entity Framework, Inner Joins with null checks generated

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have had a play with the Entity Framework and the MySQL driver.  Excuse me if this is a silly question.  Table adverts has a FK to the PK of vacancies.  Both fields are marked as NOT NULL.  I am performing a simple join:

```
 var qry = (from vacancy in context.vacancies
                       join advert in context.adverts on vacancy.id equals advert.vacancies.id
                       where advert.status == 1
                       select
                         new
                             {
                                 Id = advert.id
                             })
                            ;
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT 1 AS C1, Extent2.id FROM vacancies AS Extent1 
    INNER JOIN adverts AS Extent2 ON (Extent1.id = Extent2.vacancy_id) OR ((Extent1.id IS  NULL) AND (Extent2.vacancy_id IS  NULL))
    WHERE 1 = Extent2.status
```

Why is the EF generating "IS NULL" conditions for the join, when the columns are not marked as nullable?

Thanks,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

1. It's the provider, not the EF, which generates SQL.
2. The query is wrong anyway. [It's generally wrong to use join](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/), and all this join does is restrict the results to adverts with a vacancy, which you say is non-nullable anyway.

Comment: Smashing - thank you Craig.  Using relations instead of joins removed the null check.  Still no idea why the null checks are generated for a non-null relationship though